# The theory of transformation of arithmetic expressions into boolean circuits in zkboo

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I've read the sources of [ZKBoo](https://github.com/Sobuno/ZKBoo) where they transformed arithmetic operations of the SHA hash functions into a bunch of boolean ones. Where does this transformation arise from? How do you construct such transformation? How do you prove that these boolean operations are equivalent to arithmetic ones?

I've followed [Circuit-based Evaluation of the Arithmetic Transform of Boolean Functions](https://people.kth.se/~dubrova/PAPERS/IWLS02r.pdf) by René Krenz et al. but that seems to go the other way around: constructing arithmetic expression from a circuit.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Every language that is Turing complete has a mathematical equivalence between each other, you can translate between them. This includes both logic gate circuits and boolean expressions. And anything computable can be expressed in a Turing complete languages (so "lesser" languages can also be translated to Turing complete languages).

Comment: I am aware of that. I am more interested into the construction/transformation. This doesn't help me understand of *how* you transform that...

Comment: http://theteacher.info/index.php/fundamentals-of-computer-science-unit-1/2-logical-operations/all-topics/2928-deriving-boolean-expressions-from-logic-gate-diagrams and https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-7/converting-truth-tables-boolean-expressions/ - these are about deriving boolean expressions from gates

Comment: @PeterBocan: don't you mean "boolean operations of the SHA function into arithmetic ones"?